# Python. Mostrar resultados de for en un sólo print

Tags: python

Tengo que pedir una cadena al usuario y contar la longitud de cada palabra ingresada y al final mostrar la longitud de cada palabra, pero tengo que mostrarlo todo en una sola línea y lo que consigo es que o bien me imprima un print por cada palabra o la longitud de cada palabra pero en formato lista. ¿A alguien se le ocurre cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
palabras = input("Ingresa una cadena separada por espacios: ")
palabras = palabras.split()
#total = []
for letra in palabras:
    numero = len(letra)
    #total.append(numero)
    print(numero)
```

Comment: Si quieres hacerlo con un `for` tal como lo tienes, añade el parámetro `end=" "` al `print()` para que use un espacio como terminador en vez de un retorno de carro (que es lo que usa por defecto)

Comment: Gracias. Había probado a hacerlo así pero no me muestra lo que quiero.

Comment: ¿Por que no? deberia mostrar lo mismo que la respuesta aceptada. ¿que te muestra?

Comment: Me muestra lo mismo que sin el end = " ", es decir, cada resultado en un print.

Comment: Qué raro. Algo has copiado mal. Mira [esta demo](https://repl.it/@abul4fia/YellowTrustyLevels)

Comment: Que raro... debe ser que en la consola que tengo que utilizar el comando end no trabaja de la misma forma. He copiado tu código y sigue apareciendo cada resultado en una columna.

Comment: Ya has picado mi curiosidad :-) ¿dónde lo ejecutas? ¿qué versión de python usas?

Comment: Lo ejecuto en una consola de la plataforma online que tiene una academia de programación. En la plataforma realmente no sé que versión de Python se ejecuta, pero cuando utilizamos VisualStudio (que tb utilizamos un pluggin propio de la academia con el editor) si que utilizamos Python 3.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

una posible solución es que si no quieres que se imprima como lista, añadir cada número a una variable string e imprimirla. Para ello he cambiado la variable total para que no sea una lista sino un string y dentro del for he añadido con += a esa vaiable el número de caracteres de cada palabra y un espacio. Al salir del bucle imprimo la variable.

```
palabras = input("Ingresa una cadena separada por espacios: ")
palabras = palabras.split()

total = ""

for letra in palabras:

    numero = len(letra)
    total += str(numero) + " "

print(total)
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar el comando join dentro de un print junto con una lista para mostrar los valores especificando un espaciador, igual acá te pongo un ejemplo que puede ser lo que estas buscando

```
palabras = input("Ingresa una cadena separada por espacios: ")
palabras = palabras.split()
print("longitudes: " + ' '.join([str(len(letras)) for letras in palabras]))
```